# How to get RGB fill color values from polygones?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, qgis-2, fill

I'm trying to get color values from layers inserted into canvas. I used this code but it seems that I'm doing something wrong:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    sym = layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0]
    fill = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2().fillColor()
    p=fill.getRgb()
    print(p)
```

I always get (0,0,255,255) as a result.

[image]

Also this is how it looks Layer properties from one of the polygones in canvas.

[image]
 Is there any way or code to do this right?

I would also like to add that second fill color is added  using this code:

```
sym = layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0]
fill = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2()
fill.setFillColor(QColor.fromRgb(result[0], result[1], result[2]))
sym.appendSymbolLayer(fill)
```

Comment: The new edited part is a bit different question, there is problem with symbol index `[0]` which returns `QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer` object. And you need append fill to `QgsFillSymbol` object. So use `.symbols()` without index. Hope this helps. Also next time please ask different question in separate posts, and not editing the existing one, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You assign `layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0]` to `sym` variable

```
sym = layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0]
```

but then call `.fillColor()` on `QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2()` not on your symbol `sym`. So try:

```
fill = sym.fillColor()
```

In QGIS 3 it should be something like this (example for active layer):

```
lay = iface.activeLayer()
sym = lay.renderer().symbol()[0]
fill = sym.color()
print(fill.getRgb())
```

Comment: As you can see in 'Layer properties' I I have 2 fill colors added but when I execute your code I get values for only one of them and that is one that is not active on my canvas. Blues is on my canvas but python console shows purple. How can I get to other one?

Comment: @Ivan You get the first one because of index `[0]` in `lay.renderer().symbol()[0]`. For second fill color use `[1]`. Also note that both fill parts of symbols are "activated", you actually can't deactivate part of symbol, you only don't see the second because the first completely cover it.

Comment: I think problem is that fillcolor() and color() and different methods for different properties of layer. That is why I get wrong values. When I try to execute sym.fillColor() i get error 'QgsFillSymbolV2' object has no attribute 'fillColor' and when I use fill = sym.color() like you wrote I get values but not the fill values that I'm looking for. Also if I change to ```lay.renderer().symbol()[1]```, I get error

Comment: The problem is if I set values like this:

Comment: ```sym = layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0]
fill = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2()
fill.setFillColor(QColor.fromRgb(result[0], result[1], result[2]))
sym.appendSymbolLayer(fill)```

Comment: How can I access those values?

Comment: You are probably using QGIS 2 version, I wrote fix for your problem and also mentioned minimum example how it works in QGIS 3 (diifferent method names). If it is possible I recommend you to install QGIS 3 (at least LTR version). Anyway for append fill symbol layer try `sym = layer.rendererV2().symbols()` without `[0]` as I comment on original post.